# Simple way to expand/collapse bottom frame by pulling it up/down in Android

Tags: android

I have layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/folderContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/playerControlsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/control_view_height_min"
        android:visibility="visible">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/playerControls"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="eu.zderadicka.audioserve.fragments.ControllerFragment"
        />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I want to achieve this:

- by pulling (scrolling) up bottom frame up to expand it's height from control_view_height_min  (80dp) to control_view_height_max (200dp)

  - when fram is expanded pull it back again to control_view_height_min  by pulling (scrolling) down
  - while pulling change height as I pull
  - after stop pulling animate rest of the way

I've have been looking at "Android Sliding Up Panel", but it looks bit too complex for this case and it always pulls bottom frame to full screen.

So my question is what would be simplest way to do it in standard SDK? What to use and how? Are the some code samples close to my requirements.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: you can use the sliding up panel for this as you mentioned. You can specify up to which point you want the panel to expand so that it doesn't expand all the way to the top

Comment: "Android Sliding Up Panel" is not working - not sliding, bottom panel disappears after rotation (maybe because it's combined with support drawer)  and fast scroll is on whole screen, bottom hidden by bottom panel.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I had to find it myself. Created subclass of FrameLayout, which can be expanded/collapsed by dragging. Much simpler then Sliding Up Panel and what is more important it works in my setup. If anyone is interested (source in kotlin):

```
package eu.zderadicka.audioserve.ui

import android.animation.ValueAnimator
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.GestureDetector
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.ViewConfiguration
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import eu.zderadicka.audioserve.R
import kotlin.math.max
import kotlin.math.min
import kotlin.math.roundToInt

private const val LOG_TAG = "ExpandableFrameLayout"

class ExpandableFrameLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
                                                      defStyleAttr: Int = 0, defStyleRes: Int = 0)
    : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
    var minHeight: Int = 0
    var maxHeight: Int = 0
    val gestureDetector: GestureDetector
    var animator: ValueAnimator? = null
    private val touchSlop: Int = ViewConfiguration.get(context).scaledTouchSlop
    var midHeight: Int = 0

    fun animate(toValue: Int) {
        animator?.cancel()
        animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(height, toValue).apply {
            this.addUpdateListener {
                layoutParams.height = it.animatedValue as Int
                requestLayout()
            }
            start()

        }
    }

    inner class MyGestureListener: GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        var isDragging = false
        var startHeight = 0
        override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            startHeight = layoutParams.height
            isDragging = false
            return true
        }

//        override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
//            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fling with velocity $velocityY")
//            isDragging = true
//            if (velocityY < 0 && height < maxHeight) {
//                animate(maxHeight)
//
//            } else if (velocityY > 0 && height > minHeight) {
//                animate(minHeight)
//            }
//
//            return true
//        }

        override fun onScroll(e1: MotionEvent, e2: MotionEvent, distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float): Boolean {
            val dist = e1.rawY - e2.rawY
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Scroll in Y $dist")
            isDragging = true

            if (dist > touchSlop && height < maxHeight) {
                layoutParams.height = min(startHeight + dist.roundToInt(), maxHeight)
                requestLayout()
            } else if (dist < -touchSlop && height > minHeight) {
                layoutParams.height = max(startHeight + dist.roundToInt(), minHeight)
                requestLayout()
            }
            return true
        }

        fun dragging() = isDragging

    }

    val gestureListener = MyGestureListener()

    init {

        val customAttrs = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ExpandableFrameLayout, 0, 0)
        minHeight = customAttrs.getLayoutDimension(R.styleable.ExpandableFrameLayout_minExpandableHeight, 0)
        maxHeight = customAttrs.getLayoutDimension(R.styleable.ExpandableFrameLayout_maxExpandableHeight, 1024)
        midHeight = minHeight+ (maxHeight - minHeight) / 2
        gestureDetector = GestureDetector(context, this.gestureListener)
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Player touch $event")

        if (event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (layoutParams.height >= midHeight && layoutParams.height < maxHeight)
                    animate(maxHeight)
                else if (layoutParams.height < midHeight && layoutParams.height > minHeight)
                    animate(minHeight)

        }

        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)

    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        //listen also to all child events in upper part
        if (event.y <= minHeight) {
            onTouchEvent(event)
            // need to block up event, which were dragging
            if (event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                return gestureListener.isDragging
            }

        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
    }

    // this should be called from containing frame/activity in onPause
    fun onPause() {
        if (layoutParams.height >= minHeight) {
            layoutParams?.height = minHeight
        }

    }


}
```

Gotchas:

- when changing height or other layout properties call requestLayout
- use rawY for scrolling - ( y is related to the view and thus scrolling motion was shaky)
- as child views (buttons in my case) are consuming motion events I had to send them also from onIntercentTouchEvent plus block then unwanted ACTION_UP events.
- finally it was easier and gave better results to just use onScroll - it gave better experience (but for shorter bottom panel) - combination with onFling gave bit more complex movements.

I wish somebody told me about those things here, it could save me some hours. However it looks like SO is now more about down voting then providing useful hints.